# Make image link in static block

Tags: magento-1.9, html, link

I have this static block:

```
<div class="interior-block-slide" style="background-image: url({{media url='wysiwyg/typostores/typologancee/images/home07/vertical-blinds-full- frontend.jpg'}});">
<div class="interior-inner">
<h4 class="title"><a href="https://www.myshop.gr/en/blinds/vertical-blinds.html">VERTICAL   BLINDS <a href="https://www.myshop.gr/en/blinds/vertical-blinds.html"><span class="price">COLLECTION</span></a></h4>
</div>
</div>
```

I manage to insert href links for some words but I also want to make the whole image inside this div class :

```
<div class="interior-block-slide" style="background-image: url({{media url='wysiwyg/typostores/typologancee/images/home07/vertical-blinds-full- frontend.jpg'}});">
```

link. How can I insert in this div the href link please?

Answer (score 0):

**----- Add Background Image in static block -------**

```
  <div style="background-image: url('{{media url='wysiwyg/testing-image-name.jpeg'}}');">
       <a href="{{store direct_url="enter_your_link_here"}}">Enter Link Name</a>
  </div>
```

**------- Demo -----------**

Onclick **"Enter Link Name"** It'll redirect to your respective URL
[image]

Comment: I don't want to add any content. I just want to make this image link

Comment: First one will help for you G.G

Comment: <div style="background-image: url('{{media url='wysiwyg/testing-image-name.jpeg'}}');">
      // content here..!!!!
 </div>

Comment: Yes but I don't want to add any content. I want to click on the image. I don't understand...

Comment: Okieee Wait...I'll update my code

Comment: Mr.GG I will update my code..now you can able to add links on your image

Comment: <div style="background-image: url('{{media url='wysiwyg/testing-image-name.jpeg'}}');">
       <a href="{{store direct_url="enter_your_link_here"}}">Enter Link Name</a>
  </div>

Comment: Updated code as per your wish...Kindly check and let me know if you are facing any issue

Comment: You didn't understand what I want.

Comment: Can you explain more what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<div class="interior-block-slide" style="background-image: url('{{media url="wysiwyg/typostores/typologancee/images/home07/vertical-blinds-full- frontend.jpg"}}')">
```

Your syntax seems to be wrong.

Comment: Syntax was wrong. Picture was fine in front-page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Div that contains an image, and the image is a hyperlink:

```
<div style="width: 50%; float: left;"> 
<a href="https://www.myshop.gr/en/blinds/vertical-blinds.html">
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/typostores/typologancee/images/home07/vertical-blinds-full-frontend.jpg"}}"/>
</a></div>
```

I believe this should solve your question. If you want to add any text, put it just before the  bracket. Also, your original code had the image address ending with "full- frontend.jpg" (which includes a space) - I deleted that space from the code I pasted above.